# createjs: Shape moves mysteriously when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs, createjs

I'm new to HTML5 and JavaScript. I'm working on a very simple 'canvas' project where you have two test tubes and clicking on one reduces its level and increases the level of the other.

I've written code to do this and it works, the  only trouble is that when I click on the test tube - it moves diagonally across the screen and I don't know what's causing it.

It'd be great if you could go through the code and tell me where the problem is:

**TestTube.js**

```
TestTube.prototype.render = function(){


    this.graphics.clear();

    this.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2,1,1);
    //set stroke color black.
    this.graphics.beginStroke("#000000");
    //set fill color 
    this.graphics.beginFill(this.color);


    //START DRAWING------------------------------------

    //move to origin.
    this.graphics.moveTo(this.x,this.y);

    //draw line down to point of liquid in test tube [liquid start point]

    _level = (100 - this.level)/100;
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //draw line uptil bottom of test tube.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+(this.height-this.width/2));

    //draw the round part of test tube.
    //graphics.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,startAngle,endAngle,anticlockwise);
    this.graphics.arc(this.x + this.width/2,this.y+(this.height-this.width/2),this.width/2,Math.PI,0,true);

    //go back to upto level of liquid in tube [liquid end point]
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x+this.width,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //connect liquid start point with liquid end point to fill in liquid colour.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+_level*this.height);
    this.graphics.endFill();

    //go back to liquid end point
    this.graphics.moveTo(this.x+this.width,this.y+_level*this.height);

    //draw the rest of the test tube.
    this.graphics.lineTo(this.x+this.width,this.y);

    //stop drawing.
    this.graphics.endStroke();

}
```

**index.js**

```
chemical.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            e.target.level--;
            e.target.render();
            solution.level++;
            solution.render();
            stage.update();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you first move to (x, y):

```
this.graphics.moveTo(this.x,this.y);
```

And then add (x, y) again to your draw calls:

```
 this.graphics.lineTo(this.x,this.y+(this.height-this.width/2)); // etc
```

You only want to add (x, y) once.

Comment: But I'm simply adding values over here; I'm not assigning a new value to 'this.y' or 'this.y'